# tiny mce how to prepulate content

Tags: programming-languages, tinymce

i use Tiny MCE editor in my application. What i need is how to prepopulate content in the tiny mce editor. Content must be retrieve from previous page navigation. Some one knows how to set content of editor when the page is loaded ?
Is the a solution in Javascript, Jquery,JSP (Java) or other ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may insert that content in the html element that gets transformed into a tinymce editor.

Like

```
<textarea>My predefined content </textarea>
```

You may insert this using a server scrript language to render the content in the textarea.
Another option is to use javascript and fill the textarea just before you call the `tinymce.init` function.

Comment: for this i need to know how you get your content

Comment: The tiny mce is editor is on jsp page (struts 2 framework). The content is availabale on the page in jsp variable or OGNL variable.

Comment: I use this to test in js :
   ** function myInit(){
     $('#update').html('Some contents...');
    };
    tinyMCE.init({
     
     mode : "textareas",
     theme : "advanced",
     oninit:myInit

    });**
  

Here is my form element:

 ** <textarea name="texte" id="update" style="width:100%"></textarea>**

But i am not getting the content on textarea.
Where is the mistake, please ?

Comment: just before the tinyMCE.init call you need to update the textarea content. Example: $('textarea#update').html('my_content_to_be_set_before_init');

Comment: I test this code but it does not work. Do you have an idea. Here is my code :$('textarea#update').html('my_content_to_be_set_before_init');

tinyMCE.init({
 
 mode : "textareas",
 theme : "advanced"
});

Comment: the code looks good, can you log to console the following right before init? console.log('Size:' + $('textarea#update).size());

Comment: ok, in this case $('textarea#update) does not find your textarea, make sure your textarea is already rendered in the DOM so that $('#update') holds your textarea and $('#update').size() is 1.